# SignTool error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024885/0x8007000b) when signing msi file

Tags: signing, signtool

We recently purchased an `EV Code Signing Certificate`.
I followed instructions and I can successfully sign our built `applications (exe files)`, our `libraries (dll)`.
However, I can't sign our setup `packages (MSI files)`, I always get this error:

> SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred. Error
>   information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024885/0x8007000b)

I don't see anything in Event Viewer.
I am really stuck here, I don't not understand how same command could work for certain file types and not for msi files.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://www.questarter.com/q/-quot-error-signersign-failed-quot-2147023673-0x800704c7-27_44608218.html

Answer (score 4):

Check the log for more info:

1. Run Event Viewer app.
2. Open the event log: Event Viewer (Local) > Applications and Services
   Logs > Microsoft > Windows > AppxPackagingOM > Microsoft-Windows-AppxPackaging/Operational
3. Look for the most recent error event

In my case I had a mismatch in publisher string in Certificate and Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The following cause was [reported on a forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/06f51302-d31a-4d2a-a880-704dae40377d/signtool-error-signersign-failedquot-21470248850x8007000b?forum=wpsubmit):

> Have just found the cause: **my antivirus Trend Micro Worry Free
>   Advanced is the problem**.
>
> When I deactivate it, I can sign without any problem and it is much
>   faster to sign.
>
> Now I have to find to which part I have to set an exception in the
>   antivirus.
>
> The strange thing is that I never had any problem to sign with my
>   Authenticode certifcate,
>
> but here with an EV Code Signing certificate my antivirus blocks
>   something...

Posted by david[SDT] Monday, April 9, 2018 12:47 PM